# Countdown timer from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I'm attempting to create a countdown timer using the data I've retrieved from my database and subtracting the current time however it would depend on the ID and be displayed accordingly, here is the PHP i have so far but how would i implement it?

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// connection and query logic
require('includes/conn.inc.php');
$queryBands = "SELECT * FROM Bands WHERE bandID = :bandID";
$queryperform = $row->performance;
$performance = "SELECT performance FROM Bands WHERE bandID = :bandID";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($queryBands); 
$stmt->bindParam('bandID', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$row =$stmt->fetchObject();
?>
```

Comment: `implement` what? The are millions of ways to get an counter on a webpage. Better try something and come back if you got stuck. Currently i can not see where the issue is, you have a plan so do some.

Comment: Do you realize that PHP scripts get executed from top to bottom?

Comment: look like u repeating one thing here `$queryBands = "SELECT * FROM Bands WHERE bandID = :bandID";` and
`$performance = "SELECT performance FROM Bands WHERE bandID = :bandID";`

Comment: I realise I've done $performance again and I've amended my code accordingly, what I mean to implement is the countdown timer itself however I cannot seem to deduct the current time from the performance time as it keeps coming up with either the current date or the set in 1911 which both aren't what I want, what I want is the difference between the two and it count down changing per second